Unexpected removal of DOM elements on click
Here I am trying to build a card game in the LWC where there are 16 cards and under each card we have an icon (we have 8 different type of icons). here we have to match the icons. so below is the code:
HTML code
<template>
<lightning-card title="Memory Game" class="main-card">
    <!--Game Header (Game details)-->
    <div class="slds-p-around_small game-details slds-grid ">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-text-align--center">
            <span>{numberOfAttempts}</span> attempts
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-text-align--center">
            Timer
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-text-align--center">
            <i class="fa fa-repeat fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" onclick={reset}></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Game Body (Game Tiles)-->
<ul class="slds-p-around_small game-block">
    <template for:each={randomizeIconList} for:item="item">
            <li key = {item} class="game-tile" onclick={handleClick}>
                <i class={item} aria-hidden="true" ></i>
            </li>
    </template>
</ul>
</lightning-card>

JS file
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import FONT_AWESOME from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fontAwesome';
import {loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
export default class MemoryGameLWC extends LightningElement {
    //properties
    isRendered = false;
    @track  storeResult = [];
    @track numberOfAttempts = 0;
    //To load the CSS Resource
    renderedCallback(){
        if(this.isRendered){
            return true;
        }else{
            loadStyle(this,FONT_AWESOME+'/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css').then(
                (result) => {
                    console.log(`Fontawesmoe resource loaded successfully ${result}`);
                }
            ).catch(
                (error) => console.log(`Error while loading the resource: ${error}`)
            );
            this.isRendered = true;//sfdx project deploy start --source-dir force-app\main\default\lwc\memoryGameLWC
        }
    }
// this property stores the list of classes that are related to fontawesome icon
@track  
iconClassList = 
           ['icon fa fa-car fa-lg ',
            'icon fa fa-camera fa-lg ',
            'icon fa fa-coffee fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-diamond fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-car fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-camera fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-coffee fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-diamond fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-plane fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-plane fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-usd fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-usd fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg',
            'icon fa fa-firefox fa-lg ',
            'icon fa fa-firefox fa-lg ',];

//This method will randomize the iconList
    get randomizeIconList(){
      let sample =   this.iconClassList;
      for(let i=0;i<16;i++){
       let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
       let a = sample[i];
       sample[i]=sample[randomNumber];
       sample[randomNumber]=a;
      }
      console.log(sample);
      return sample;
    }
   
//this method adds a CSS class to the game tile which shows the icon and animates the Rotation
    handleClick(event){
        let card = event.target;//here we are getting the tile
        //console.log('Clicked on the tile',this.numberOfAttempts);
        let iconClass = card.querySelector(".icon").classList;//here we are the child of the tile that is icon class list
        let currentIconClass = iconClass[2];
        card.classList.add("animate","disable");//this will add the following css classes to animate and disable to the card for clicks
        card.querySelector(".icon").classList.add("show");// by adding the class show icon will be displayed

        //this is the logic to find the correct card match  
          this.storeResult = [...this.storeResult, card];
          console.log('This is the value of the Array: ',this.storeResult); 

          if(this.storeResult.length == 2 ){
            //if the first card and second card matches then sucess and new color will be added that is success class will be added
            if(this.storeResult[0].querySelector(".icon").classList[2] === this.storeResult[1].querySelector(".icon").classList[2])
                {
                console.log('successFull Match ',this.storeResult[0].classList);
                this.storeResult[0].classList.add("success");
                this.storeResult[1].classList.add("success");
                this.storeResult = [];
                }
            else{
                console.log(`not a match ${this.storeResult[0].querySelector(".icon").classList} is not equal to ${this.storeResult[1].querySelector(".icon").classList}`);
                let [firstCard, secondCard] = this.storeResult;
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    console.log(`this is the value in set timeout`);
                    firstCard.classList.remove("animate","disable");
                    firstCard.querySelector(".icon").classList.remove("show");
                    secondCard.classList.remove("animate","disable");
                    secondCard.querySelector(".icon").classList.remove("show");
                 },1000);
                this.storeResult = [];
               }
               this.updateNumberOfAttempts();
           }
    }

// this method is to reset the tiles to its original state that is to hide all the icons again and start the game from start
    reset(event){
        let resetIcon = event.target;
        resetIcon.classList.add("resetAnimate");//this is to animate the reset icon 
        let cardList = this.template.querySelectorAll('.game-tile');
        cardList.forEach((currentItem) =>{
            currentItem.classList.remove("animate","disable","success");//remving the disable class so that the tile is clickable again
            //console.log('this is from the reset for each loop: ',currentItem.querySelector(".icon").classList);
            currentItem.querySelector(".icon").classList.remove("show");
        } ); // this will remove the css classes making all the tiles blank again
        setTimeout(() => {
           // console.log('This message is from settimeout',resetIcon.classList);
            resetIcon.classList.remove("resetAnimate");
           // console.log('This message is from settimeout',resetIcon.classList);
           }
            ,2000);//this will remove the reset animation class after 2 sec

            this.storeResult = [] ; //removing all the elements in the array as reset
    }

    updateNumberOfAttempts(){
        this.numberOfAttempts ++;
    }
}

CSS file
.main-card{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.game-block{
    color: black;  
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); 
    gap: 5px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 8px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.game-tile{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: thistle;
    font-size: 0;
    }
.icon{
    font-size: 33px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.show{
    visibility: visible;
}

.game-tile.animate{
  animation-name: cardFlip;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-direction: linear;
  background-color: aqua;
}
@keyframes cardFlip {
    0%   {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    50%  {transform: rotateY(90deg);}
    100% {transform: rotateY(180deg);}
  }

.resetAnimate{
    animation-name: rotateClockwise;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    animation-direction: linear;
}

@keyframes rotateClockwise {
    0%   {transform: rotatez(0deg);}
    50%  {transform: rotatez(90deg);}
    100% {transform: rotatez(180deg);}
}

.disable{
    pointer-events: none;
}

.game-tile.success{
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

in the fifth line of the HTML code when I am trying to add {numberOfAttempts} property then UI is not behaving as expected that is some elements are being removed from the DOM.
below is the screenshot of the game without {numberOfAttempts} where this is hardcoded to 1(the game is working as expected):

below is the screenshot when I am using dynamic value that is {number of Attempts} some of the DOM elements are removed unexpectedly:

so, just wanted to know where I am going wrong?

Congrats for the memory game - nice!
I'm not sure why the provided code uses a get function to calculate the matrix. getters are called more often than setters. In order to prevent unnecessary code executions, usually setters are used to calculate the values returned by getters. In the memory game however, no input is required. It's therefore best to move the calculation of the matrix into the connectedCallback, something like:
randomizeIconList;

connectedCallback(event) {
    this.populateMatrix();
}

populateMatrix(){
    let sample =  this.iconClassList;
    ...
    this.randomizeIconList = sample;
}

This should fix the problem, because currently the getter is often called, when the DOM needs to be re-rendered - e.g. because numberOfAttempts is incremented ;-)
Just one other observation: If
<template for:each=... for:item="item">

is used, we have to make damn sure the key of the item is different in each iteration. But if the memory game is to work, there necessarily must be duplicates in the current iterator. Putting a break point before returning from the current get randomizeIconList() and inspecting the array, these duplicates become obvious. Salesforce often manages to render the list nevertheless, but we can't rely on it. It's for this reason template iterators are usually implemented to operate on (lists of) objects. In the given case, one could use something like:
const cards = [];
for(let i=0; i<16; i++) {
    ...
    cards.push({
        id: ''+i, // string recommended
        iconClass: sample[i]
    });
}
this.randomizeIconList = [...cards];

Markup:
<li key={item.id} ...>
    <i class={item.iconClass} ...></i>

Good luck with this neat little project!

Thanks a lot for the response this resolved the issue
